# Sharing a path string between modules in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to make a gui that displays a path to a file, and the user can change it anytime. I have my defaults which are in my first script.The following is a simplified version without any of the gui stuff. But then the user pushes a button and it runs a different script (script2). In this script, the information on the file is read.

script1:

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp 
import script2


specsfile = mp.Array('c',1000, lock=True)
path_save = mp.Array('c',1000, lock=True)

p = mp.Process(target=script2, args=(specsfile,path_save))
p.start()


specsfile = '//_an_excel_sheet_directory.xlsx'
path_save = '//path/to/my/directory/'    


subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'script2.py'])
```

script2:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from script1 import specsfile
from script1 import path_save


print(specsfile)


spec= pd.read_excel(specsfile)
```

When I run it, it gives me this error: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

I'm not sure if I'm initializing this wrong or not. I've never used multiprocessing but I was reading about some recommendations for that when sharing data. so basically I want to initialize a specsfile string and a path_save string but when it changes,I want it to be reflected and sent to specs2 file.

Comment: I really can't get my head around what `specsfile = mp.Array('c',1000, lock=True)` or `path_save = mp.Array('c',1000, lock=True)` is for, which isn't helped by the fact you don't show `test_report`.

Comment: I'm assuming this is how you initialize the shared data? Unless I don't have to. 
You're right. I made corrections. It's supposed to be script2

Comment: I don't think I have a shot at answering this because I still don't properly understand the structure you've chosen. Note that you define `specsfile` and `path_save` twice in `script1`.

Comment: Does it give a line number? Do you have permission to read the file?

Comment: You seem to be trying to run a module as a Process function. That isn’t going to work. Plus, you then try to run the same thing as a script with subprocess. I can’t imagine why you’d want both in the same program. Which one do you actually want to do?

Comment: Anyway, if you're trying to do `multiprocessing`, the documentation for that module has extensive examples for the right way to do this, but the key thing is that you need to pass a _function_, not a module, and you need to either pass the arguments to that function (which will copy them and send them over a pipe, which can be slow, and means you're not sharing them anymore), wrap them up with shared memory `Value` or `Array` (you'll want to look at the numpy docs for how to do that with numpy arrays) and appropriate cross-process locking, or wrap them up in a `Manager`.

Comment: If you're trying to do `subprocess`, you really can't do it this way. The only easy way to share data with as subprocess is to pass it over stdin and stdout, or store it in a file and pass the filename as a command-line argument. (Well, you can `mmap` a file, allocate the arrays in the space, and pass the fd to the child process in one of two ways, but that's probably not what you want, and very hard to explain if you don't already know how Unix fds and C memory management work.)